# How to call Rest APIs from Android

Tags: android, capacitor

I have Rest APIs which is currently running on HTTPS mode, 10 days back my APIs are Running on HTTP mode, to access the HTTP APIs I have use the below process:

AndroidMainfest.xml:

```
       <application
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config">
```

on res/xml folder I have created network_security_config.xml

network_security_config.xml code:

```
         <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
         <network-security-config>
            <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
               <domain includeSubdomains="true">api.***.****.in</domain>
            </domain-config>
         </network-security-config>
```

Then I am able to access the APIs from the Android App, But after converting my APIs into HTTPS mode I can't able to access it.

can anyone help me with this.

Comment: You need these lines if you are using the HTTP APIs. But if you are using HTTPS APIs remove these lines and everything would be good to go.

Comment: looks like your certificate is not good or not trusted by Android

Comment: @jcesarmobile  How can I add client-side certificate on Android

Comment: You don’t need a client side certificate, you have to use a trusted certificate on the server

Comment: @jcesarmobile  I am able to access the Rest APIs  from the browser, but from the android app I can't.

Comment: That doesn't matter, your computer can trust a certificate that Android doesn't, even some Android OS version can trust it and another one doesn't. But also check the device time and date, if not properly set it can fail to accept some SSL certificates.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a single line code in Manifest file inside application tag.

```
  android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

Example:

```
 <application
    android:name=".MyApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
```

Comment: I have tried by adding the android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" but I am getting this error:

E/chromium: [ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(946)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -202